# Dynamically and responsively centering loader image with table dimensions

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm using DataTables for building a table. I'd like to use my own loader image with a simple transparent background instead of DataTable's  `processing` indicator (default or customized one), since it doesn't get centered properly when there are few records.

How can I center my loader (image+background) dynamically and responsively with table dimensions?

Here are two examples for a centeralized loader:

[image]

[image]

[Current (wrong) Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/391kn9n4/3/)

**Clarification** (Thanks to @Andrei Gheorghiu comment):

I want the loader to be centered with the rows area, i.e., the table excluding its headers, footers or other elements - as shown in the images above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the default spinner is centered. It looks off because your columns are unequal. You can solve this two ways:

- a) move the spinner to "look" centered (I wouldn't go this route)
- b) make the center column actually centered in the table.

For b), considering you have 3 columns, I'd use

```css
#FactoryTable td:first-child,#FactoryTable td:last-child {
  width: 30%;
}
```

I'm not sure how the vertical centering is done in this plugin but I now know from your question you'd like the custom spinner vertically aligned in the content area of the table, excluding both header and footer.

In general cases, the way you do this is by placing the item to be centered inside the container you want to center in, give container `position:relative` and child

```css
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

But that's not possible for tables, so you need a different approach. You have to create a centering container, position it on top of the table body and than center the image inside with a technique of your choice. The greatest advantage of this technique is that it **disables** user's ability to interact with the table while the table is being loaded, which might prevent various failures and errors in the system, on both back-end and front-end.

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/pz9zd308/) with everything I mentioned so far. Key points are:

- centering image in #spinner using flexbox
- making `first-child` and `last-child` td's equal so the center one is actually centered
- placing the script that positions and sizes #spinner on top of table inside a function (`resizeSpinner()`) that gets called on window `resize` and `load` events. Note you should also trigger this function after any other javascript code that can alter the size of your table.

---

Looking closer at resulting code, there are two more things to add:

- you can safely (and you should) put the `DataTable` instance inside `table` var when you initiate it. Trying to do so afterwards results into re-initiating it, which clearly should not happen. What you're doing is init DataTable, and throw it away to init it again so you place it inside `table` var.
- binding on either `scroll` or `resize` events (as I did above) is, in principle, to be avoided.

In this particular case, the DOM manipulation we're doing is minor and it's really hard to believe any device/browser combo will ever encounter problems executing the `resizeSpinner()` function on each browser resize, but, for the sake of principle and good practice, you should be loading a small library called [`jQuery Throttle/Debounce`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) which enables us to throttle a function (specify a minimum interval between subsequent runs of the function). I don't particularly recommend the above plugin but, since you already use `jQuery` I guess the jQuery equivalent should be used. I personally use `lodash` a lot, a library which includes its own versions of `throttle` and `debounce`, with slightly different syntax than the jQuery plugin.
To read more on the specific differences between throttle and debounce, read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

So the improved version of your fiddle would be:

```js
var table = $('#FactoryTable').DataTable({
  "dom": "tipr",
  "pagingType": "simple",
});

table.row.add([1, 2, 3]).draw(false);
table.row.add([1, 2, 3]).draw(false);
table.row.add([1, 2, 3]).draw(false);
table.row.add([1, 2, 3]).draw(false);

var resizeSpinner = $.throttle(100, false, function() {
  var fH = '#FactoryTable',
      thh = $(fH + ' thead').height();
  $('#spinner').css({
    height: ($(fH).height() - thh) + 'px',
    top: thh + 'px'
  });
})
resizeSpinner();
$(window).on('load resize', resizeSpinner);
```

```css
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* add this to make left and right columns equal,
 * thus centering the contents of the center column in the table 
 * but keep in mind for any table with more than 3 columns 30% is 
 * too much for a column width.
 */

#FactoryTable td:first-child,
#FactoryTable td:last-child {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

<div id="Table">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive cell-border" id="FactoryTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="active">
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Team</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <span id="spinner" class="myspinner"><img src="http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif"></span>
  <span id="transp"></span>
</div>
```

It could probably be cleaned up more, but I don't know anything about the rest of your project so I'll leave it as it is. Don't forget to [prefix CSS](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting approach, but it doesn't work properly. You can see in the fiddle you provided that it's not centralized (also, try it with one-line or two-lines table, and it would be more salient).

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This effect can be created using plain CSS. You can go ahead and remove

```
var height = $('#FactoryTable').height();
var width = $('#FactoryTable').width();
$("#spinner").css('top', height * 0.50);
$("#spinner").css('left', width * 0.50);
$("#transp").css('height', height * 0.50);
$("#transp").css('top', height * 0.50);
```

from your JS.

And add the following CSS styles:

```
#Table
{
  position: relative;
}

.myspinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 52%;
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
}

#transp {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(250,250,250,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

A Fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/391kn9n4/10/).

Comment: Thanks! It works almost perfectly, except when the table is narrowed so that the `datatables_info` and `datatables_paginate` elements are pushed down and the spinner goes down with them and get decentralized.

Comment: Fixed. Add

`@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .myspinner {
   margin-top: -20px;
 }
}`

To your styles. Updated link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/391kn9n4/11/)

Comment: Proper centering is `top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` This answer is *not* centered, but trying to create the illusion of centering based on existing data. The data inside the table creates unequal columns, with the one in the middle slightly offset to the right because the left-most col is wider than the right-most col. Centering the spinner based on data is always going to fail, depending on device and screen size. If you want both centered, make the columns equal and they will align with the default spinner (which is properly centered).

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu  I made sure the centering wasn't exactly at 50%, as the two screenshots provided in the question showed the spinner directly sitting over the _center_ of the _second_ column. I am aware that `left: 50%; right: 50%` is exactly in the center of the parent element.

Comment: Anyway, from the clarification made to the question, it looks like the "real" centering should be both vertically and horizontally on the content area of the table itself. Excluding header and footer. Which, unfortunately, for this plugin, is only possible via JavaScript, by calculating it on the fly each time the table changes or the window changes. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu, Gosh, I wish I could pm you...you surely seem to really understand what I need. I'd be glad for your suggestions, alternatives and what not.

Comment: Here's what [you want](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/pz9zd308/), @HeyJude. Try to be more specific on your next questions. If you want to contact me, you can, using the contact form of the website linked in my profile. However, for this issue at least, I don't see a reason for it, as I believe it's solved. Have a glorious day! :)

Comment: Wouldn't you like to post it as an answer? I'd also like to ask your opinion about the need to make it a function that is called on each screen resize. Is it a bad practice, and I thus need to look for an entire different table structuring?